# Mysql query that performs sums between different tables

Tags: database, services

I am struggling to make a query in a custom service function in Drupal 7, which should make 3 sums. In each table (3), there are 2 records saved with the following values:

- field_data_field_monto_15pts with field [field_monto_15pts_value] data: 5 and 6
- field_data_field_monto_14pts with field [field_monto_14pts_value] data: 3 and 4
- field_data_field_monto_13pts with field [field_monto_13pts_value] data: 1 and 2

The service function that performs the query and returns data in the JSON format is the following.

```
$cantidad = db_query('
  SELECT SUM(field_monto_15pts_value) AS 15pts,  
         SUM(field_monto_14pts_value) AS 14pts,  
         SUM(field_monto_13pts_value) AS 13pts  
  FROM {field_data_field_monto_15pts},  {field_data_field_monto_14pts},  {field_data_field_monto_13pts}')  
  ->fetchAssoc();

return $cantidad;
```

What I expect from the function is the following values.

```
{
  "15pts": "11",
   "14pts": "7",  
   "13pts": "3"  
}
```

What the function returns is this.

```
{  
   "15pts": "44",  
   "14pts": "28",  
   "13pts": "12"  
}
```

What is wrong in the code I am using?

Answer (score 0):

Well ... Since no one had this problem, or nobody has a solution, I put the solution that I have given on the site https://www.drupal.org/node/2898276

The problem is how I wrote the query to the database. A Cartesian product is produced. After rewriting the query was solved. It was finally written:

```
$lo_que_che= db_query('SELECT (SELECT SUM(field_monto_15pts_value) AS 15pts FROM {field_data_field_monto_15pts}) 15pts, (SELECT SUM(field_monto_14pts_value) AS 14pts FROM {field_data_field_monto_14pts}) 14pts, SUM(field_monto_13pts_value) AS 13pts FROM field_data_field_monto_13pts}') ->fetchAssoc();  return $lo_que_che;
```